# Firebase Phone Auth - RecaptchaVerifier Type Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha

I am trying to implement Firebase Phone Number Authentication as described [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

However when I try try and create the RecaptchaVerifier object as per the docs:

```
window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
```

I get the following error:

> ***Uncaught TypeError:*** Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
>       at new FirebaseAppImpl.(anonymous function)

which seems to be from this line of code in the Firebase SDK:

```
 var serviceFxn = this._getService.bind(this, name);
```

Has anyone successfully implemented this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wrongly trying to create the RecaptchaVerifier on the already initialised FirebaseApp rather than the actual module. This code is actually working fine:

`window.recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');`

Comment: So what changed ? you do exactly the same thing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it some more. Didn't get what you did?